# Image now showing up on screen while using Material UI <Image> props

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I installed and imported `mui-image` into my React project and used it as a component `<Image>`. The issue is my png image did not showed up on screen (neither svg). However, I inserted a random image link on the internet and it worked. Does that mean my the issue is from my png image? And how do I fix this bug?

I installed `npm i mui-image`then imported `import { Image } from "mui-image"` to my index.js file

then imported my png image as
`import { mypng } from "../img/mypng.png";`

`...<Image src={mypng} />`
(mypng has the dimension of: 2880 × 800)

However, it worked with a random url:
`<Image src="https://source.unsplash.com/200x200" />`

I would really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

You're using object deconstruction in your import. `"../img/mypng.png"` has no property called mypng. Try :

```
import mypng from "../img/mypng.png";
```

Comment: I did try but nothing has changed